# Duplicate and incorrect result trying to append String to Custom StringBuilder

Tags: java, serialization, append, stringbuilder, charsequence

I'm trying to append a String to StringBuilder I have the code setup.

This is what I am inputting

`this = "is"\na = "test"`

This is the output I'm getting

```
    this = "is"
    this = "is"
a = "test"
```

my expected output is

```
    this = "is"
    a = "test"
```

Here is my code that is doing the work. I have a class that `implements`
the following classes `CharSequence, Appendable, Serializable`

and then I override the append using the code below

```
@Override
public IndentingStringBuilder append(CharSequence csq) {
    append(csq, 0, csq.length());
    return this;
}

@Override
public IndentingStringBuilder append(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        if (csq.charAt(start) == '\n') {
            writeLine(csq.toString(), start);
            stringBuilder.append(newLine);
            beginningOfLine = true;
            start++;
        } else {
            start++;
        }
    }
    writeLine(csq.toString(), start);
    return this;
}

private void writeLine(String str, int end) {
    if (beginningOfLine && end > 0) {
        writeIndent();
        beginningOfLine = false;
    }
    stringBuilder.append(str, 0, end);
}

private void writeIndent() {
    for (int i = 0; i < indentLevel; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(' ');
    }
}
```

this are the global vars defined

```
private static final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
private int indentLevel = 0;
private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

What am I doing wrong here? and how would I fix this to get correct results for my input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always passing to `writeLine` the entire input `CharSequence`, and `writeLine` always appends the characters of the input `String` starting at the first character.

Therefore, the first call to `writeLine` appends

```
    this = "is"
```

and the second call appends

```
    this = "is"
a = "test"
```

You can pass another argument to `writeLine`:

```
private void writeLine(String str, int from, int to) {
    if (beginningOfLine && to > 0) {
        writeIndent();
        beginningOfLine = false;
    }
    stringBuilder.append(str, from, to);
}
```

and call it from `append` as follows:

```
public IndentingStringBuilder append(CharSequence csq, int start, int end) {
    int from = 0;
    while (start < end) {
        if (csq.charAt(start) == '\n') {
            writeLine(csq.toString(), from, start);
            from = start + 1;
            stringBuilder.append(newLine);
            beginningOfLine = true;
            start++;
        } else {
            start++;
        }
    }
    writeLine(csq.toString(), from, start);
    return this;
}
```

As an alternative, you can pass to `writeLine` a `subSequence` of `csq`.

Comment: I see, Thanks for clearing up on this. How ever I am still unaware how I could fix this.

Comment: @James see edit. This is untested, `from` may have to be incremented by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly for the test case I provided.